# How to disable any write operations in Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have microservice which just reads data from elasticsearch cluster. I want to disable all PUT operations related to mappings at boot time for the index. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this in Spring Data Elasticsearch. But if it's your microservice that accesses the cluster, why do any changing calls at all?

You can use the user and role management from Elasticsearch (xpack) to create a Elasticsearch user that can only read from indices, and then use the basic authentication (available as of Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2) in Spring Data Elastcsearch to authenticate against Elasticsearch.

Comment: Hello, sorry for misleading problem description - I was thinking about mappings. Is there any way how to disable PUT operations on mappings at the boot time?

Comment: when reading the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-privileges.html it seems that the grant for writing documents to the index also gives access to store a mapping. Both go to the same endpoint with the exception that indexing also has _doc in the path.

Comment: `createIndex = false` did the job actually.